# dynamic tooltip for bootstrap select

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-selectors, bootstrap-selectpicker

I need to add dynamic tooltip to bootstrap select dropdown when I move the mouse over item tooltip text should showa its value.
But in my example only shows static text or shows all items value together!(in pictures)
[ https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2018/9/7/21093ba294817db8cb4cf968e467fe64-full.png ]
How I can put each item value to item tooltip?

Thanks

```
// in this I try to add each span text to each li element???
    var tooltipMap = {};
    $('#id').data('selectpicker').$lis.each(function () {
    var li = $(this);
    var elementtext = li.find('span.text').text();
    var tooltipString = tooltipMap[elementtext];
    if (tooltipString){
        li.tooltip({ trigger: 'hover', placement: 'right', title: tooltipString }); }

//show only static text inside tooltip for all loaded items
    $('#id').data('selectpicker').$lis.attr('title', 'static text').tooltip();});
```

Comment: I found a solution myself thanks

Answer (score 0):

working edition

```
 $("#id").each(function (i) {

                if ( i > 0 ) {
                    var test= "title is : " + $(this).text();

                    $(this).attr("title", sube).tooltip();
                   //alert(test);
                }

        });
```

working for static text

```
$('#id').on('shown.bs.select', function () {
$($(this).data('selectpicker').current.elements).attr('title', sube).tooltip();
 });
```